# How to get a tag inner html with is inside a div?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am new to javascript and that's why maybe I am very poor with `js`.

I am trying to get tag inner HTML which is inside a div parent tag.

I tried many times, but, because of my poor knowledge, I can't get its inner HTML. I can easily get its inner HTML if its data doesn't fetch from the database.

Here is my HTML with php[fetching data]

```
    <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die("cannot connect to server"); 
    mysql_select_db("tsms")or die("cannot select DB");
    $sql = "select * from vendors";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
      echo '<div style="width:25%;margin-right:20px;margin-left:10px;cursor:pointer;" class="w3-third w3-section" id="home_vendorslist" onclick="gethead()">
            <div class="w3-card-4">
            <img src="'.$row["pic_path"].'" style="height: 200px;width: 100%">
            <div style="position: relative;" class="w3-container w3-white">
            <h4 id="venpichead" class="w3-center" style="color: black;">'.$row["heading"].'</h4>
            <p style="height: 100px;overflow: auto;">'.$row["body"].'</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>';
    }
?>
```

Here many class added from w3 CSS.

I want to get  tag inner HTML, whenever anyone clicks any of the main . That's why i call onclick="gethead()" function.

The onclick function code

```
  function gethead()
  {
     alert(document.getElementById("venpichead").innerHTML);
  }
```

My main problem is that it returns only one value [same value] every time.

I added all of my div data with a pic below:

[image: div data fetched from database]

When I click any of div, it only return(alert) only "cisco". Why? Any solution?

Comment: all your elements id must be unique. when you assign an id in a loop like that you are creating a buttload of elements with same ids.

Comment: IDs have to be unique to a page. If you have 4 `<h4>` with the same ID, then the value of the first `<h4>` is returned.

Comment: but its may be cant unique because my data is fatched from databse.

Comment: @nayanchowdhury they can absolutely be unique. Use an incrementor in your loop, i.e. `id="venpichead-' . $i . '"` = `venpichead-0`, `venpichead-1`, `venpichead-2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should be using/creating unique IDs and NOT re-using them!** Though the following should work.

Pass `this` into your `onclick`function and then use `querySelector()` to search within the element. [querySelector() support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector).

Basic example.

```js
function gethead( el ) {
  alert( el.querySelector( '#venpichead' ).innerHTML );
}
```

```html
<div onclick="gethead( this )">
  <h4 id="venpichead">One</h4>
</div>

<div onclick="gethead( this )">
  <h4 id="venpichead">Two</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because ID selector (id = "venpichead") is unique, ergo, only the first element will keep this attribute.

The solution is use "class" attribute, and catch the event for each element:

```
<h4 class="venpichead" class="w3-center" style="color: black;" onclick="gethead">

function gethead()
{
    alert(this.innerHTML);
}
```

BTW: JQuery is recommended for events. It could be something like this:

```
jQuery('.venpichead').click( function () {
    alert(jQuery(this).html());
});
```

Comment: but i wants to click anywhere of the main <div>.the above solution will allow me to click on only <h4>

Answer (score 0):

in your PHP you define `<h4 id="venpichead"` - you do it three times. But `id` should be unique in the HTML document. You need to use another way to handle the event click: `onclick="gethead(this)`.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
      echo '<div style="width:25%;margin-right:20px;margin-left:10px;cursor:pointer;" class="w3-third w3-section home_vendorslist" onclick="gethead(this)">
            <div class="w3-card-4">
            <img src="'.$row["pic_path"].'" style="height: 200px;width: 100%">
            <div style="position: relative;" class="w3-container w3-white">
            <h4 class="w3-center venpichead" style="color: black;">'.$row["heading"].'</h4>
            <p style="height: 100px;overflow: auto;">'.$row["body"].'</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>';
    }
```

javascript:

```
function gethead(obj)
  {
     alert(obj.getElementsByClassName("venpichead")[0].innerHTML);
  }
```

Comment: if i do this it will return all the inner html inside id home_vendorslist.but i want only <h4> inner html

Comment: I've changed the answer. Also I've moved `home_vendorslist` from id to class in the first line of `echo`

Comment: its work for me.but i am confused why you use [0] with ("venpichead")[0] .why not only ("venpichead").

Comment: @nayanchowdhury `getElementsByClassName()` can return more than one element so you access by index. `[ 0 ]` gives you the first matched element.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` always returns array. So you need to get its value by index even when there is only one value.

Answer (score 0):

You may only have one instance of an `id` value within your HTML.  You are creating the title of each vendor with the same "venpichead" `id` for the `h4` element.

Since each `id` is supposed to be unique, the `getElementById` method will only ever reference the first instance that it finds of an `id` (which, in this case, contains the word "CISCO").

Try changing it to use a common `class`, instead of an `id`.  However, you will also need to change up your logic a little bit, as well, since `getElementByClassName` will get all of the `h4` elements on the page.  So, you will either need to loop through them to get to the one that you want, or reduce the scope of `getElementByClassName`, so that it only finds the one that you are looking for (e.g., use the element that you clicked on as the scope, rather than `document`).

**Note:** You have some other `id` values that are being repeated in your code . . . you should clean those up too.   ;)

Answer (score 0):

Because **id** attribute should be unique.
document.getElementById() method return first element with that id.
You are running that echo in loop, so you have multiple elements with that id.